# Convert csv data catalogue to word2vec object

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-visualization, word2vec

I found a [Spotify csv data catalogue](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-01-21/spotify_songs.csv), but I want to convert it into word2vec (specifically the track title and artist name) and show the vector in t-SNE. I saw that it's common to save your word2vec results TO csv, but is it possible to convert csv files to word2vec object?

Answer (score 0):

It is not common to save word-vectors to CSV.

And, that file you've linked isn't typical dense high-dimensional word-vector embedding data.

Rather, there are a few named, meaningful scalar values from Spotify's analysis. (I see things like `danceability`, `energy`, `speechiness`, etc.)

An actual word2vec model *doesn't* usually label the values with such easily-interpretable names.

This might still be interesting multi-dimensional data for clustering/plotting, but you wouldn't at any point convert it to a "word2vec object" to do that.

(And, if you did either train some word-vectors from the artist/title info alone, or use external word-vectors to convert the artist/title to word-vector dimensions, the results might be disappointing - those words may not characterize the underlying patterns very well, except in some really coarse ways that are obvious from shared words (like love-songs having 'love' in the title, or those with 'remix' in the title being a little more dancey, etc).

What is your real ultimate goal in working with this data?